# Selecionar elemento anterior CSS

Tags: html, css, table

Estou tentando selecionar o outro elemento pai de uma *table*, mas não esta rolando via *CSS*.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> 
              <p>R$ 200,00</span></p>
              <span class="small">Comprar agora</span>
        </label>
     </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <div class="exibe-detalhes">
       Aqui vem o conteudo
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.exibir-detalhes {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + .exibir-detalhes {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Com CSS vc só consegue selecionar irmãos, filhos ou adjacentes. Teria que usar JavaScript para isso.

Comment: Obrigado, com jquery consigo?

Comment: Ele não poderia usar classes junto com ntn-child(2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas com CSS não é possível fazer isso.

Com *Jquery* ficaria assim:

OBS: O nome da tua classe `exibir-detalhes` estava com nome diferente no teu html e css, entao deixei ambas com o mesmo nome.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.voo-radio').on('change', function() {
    $('.exibir-detalhes').hide();
    
    $($(this).parents('tr').next().find('.exibir-detalhes')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.exibir-detalhes {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
      <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
    </td> 
  </tr> 

  <tr> 
    <td> 
      <div class="exibir-detalhes"> aqui vem um teste 1 </div>
    </td> 
  </tr> 
  
  <tr>  
    <td> 
        <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio"> 
    </td>
  </tr> 
  
  <tr> 
      <td> 
          <div class="exibir-detalhes"> aqui vem um teste 2 </div> 
      </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Consegui chegar neste resultado, mas são varias linhas com input e cada uma delas vai ter o TR relacionado a ela, como poderia fazer com que ativa somente a TR referente ao input radio?

Comment: Alterei minha resposta. Da uma olhada pra ver se é isso que tu quer.

Comment: Seria neste estilo,só que com muito mais resultados
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="exibir-detalhes">
                        aqui vem um teste 1 </div>
</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <div class="exibir-detalhes">
 aqui vem um teste 2
</div>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: Modifiquei o codigo de acordo com essa estrutura.

Answer (score 0):

> Tinha um erro na sua classe: no CSS está `exibir-detalhes` e no
>   elemento `exibe-detalhes`.

Com jQuery você pode fazer desta forma, procurando o elemento da `tr` posterior ao do `radio` clicado:

```js
$(".voo-radio").click(function(){

   $(".exibir-detalhes")
   .hide();
   
   $(this)
   .closest("tr")
   .next("tr")
   .find(".exibir-detalhes")
   .show();
});
```

```css
.exibir-detalhes {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> 
              <p>R$ 200,00</span></p>
              <span class="small">Comprar agora</span>
        </label>
     </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <div class="exibir-detalhes">
       Aqui vem o conteudo
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" class="voo-radio" name="voo-radio">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> 
              <p>R$ 200,00</span></p>
              <span class="small">Comprar agora</span>
        </label>
     </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
      <div class="exibir-detalhes">
       Aqui vem o conteudo
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show isso mesmo! 
Muito Obrigado!